# Will my 3D printer significantly get quieter after upgrading from Creality board 2.5.2 to BTT SKR Turbo 1.4

Tags: creality-cr-10, stepper-driver, skr-v1.4, tmc2208, tmc2209

I have a Creality CR10 v3, which includes a board v2.5.2 with built-in TMC2208 stepper motor drivers.

I have read that it is still 8-bit (I thought that advertising a "silent board" meant it was 32-bit) and that upgrading to a 32-bit will improve a lot the background noise.

I don't really understand how noise is generated in the first place, but I have the strong feeling that a big percentage of the noise is in fact the result of the fans!

These are the ones bothering me when I work in the same room as the printer.

So will the upgrade from a creality board to BTT SKR Turbo 1.4 (already in my possession) with TMC2209 or TMC2226 (not yet in my possession) drivers help?

Will I be able to remove some of the fans, or will I keep the same noise from these fans?

How to make sure that I am not already in the best noise configuration I can hope for with a CR10 ?

Side question: will any of the hacks found online (dampers, for instance) really help ?

Answer (score 2):

"Silent" board means TMC steppers. It has nothing to do with whether the microcontroller on it is 8- or 32-bit, and a 32-bit microcontroller will not in general get you any sound-reduction benefits. What it would let you do is build Marlin firmware with more advanced options switched on. (Note: this doesn't apply to Klipper, which is happy running advanced stuff on a slow 8-bit board because the main logic runs on a full CPU like a Raspberry Pi.)

If you want to reduce fan noise, you'll need to buy quieter replacement fans or look for passive cooling (big heat sinks, heat pipes, etc.) to use in place of one or more of the fans.

Comment: Thanks, that's sad (for me) to read. I guess I'll soon reach a point where I'll have so many spare parts from my printer pimping mistakes, that I'll be able to assemble a second 3D printer. Can you share some readings on alternative cooling systems, please?

Comment: Also, how can I determine all the advanced options that are not running currently with my 8-bit board? For me, I thought I was using full marlin 2.0.9 capabilities.